# How to highlight Flutter / DART code segment in Overleaf Latex?

Tags: dart, latex, document, overleaf

I made a project with Flutter, with Dart language, and I'm trying to write a report on it. I need to copy code segments to the document, however I can't highlight my dart code. The closest I can get is with the java highlight, but it's still not quite right...

```
\begin{minted}{java} 
//my dart code
\end{minted}
```

Thanks, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minted package is based on Pygments. Pygments lists [Dart](https://pygments.org/languages/) as a supported language, so it should work (for me it works). May be the problem is otherwise. Two possible problems/solutions:

- Updating the packages with your LaTeX distribution.
- If you are using another directory to put all output files o auxiliary files with `--output-directory=dir` or `--aux-directory=dir` commands, use the command `\usepackage[outputdir=dir]{minted}` to point to same directory.